# Can I call Web API from a client configured to call an .asmx service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking at converting an existing web service into a Web API. I've only worked with a WS a little bit and it was a long time ago. What I do remember is that in my project I would make reference to a service location and then use that reference to call whatever method I needed. 
EX: I would reference http://mydomain/webservicename/mobile.asmx and then would call objWS.MethodName() what was coded within the mobile.asmx file.

If I convert over to using a Web API I would basically call the HTTP by going to something like http://mydomain/controllername/myMethod.

As of right now I don't have access to the client code to be able to change the way that it calls the service. That being said am I stuck with using a traditional web service vs web api?

This is an app on a handheld scanner that I believe is running Windows CE. We are having some connectivity issues/database deadlocks and I was asked to look at it and see if I can help out. The current WS code is overly complicated IMO since it's only doing either an insert or an update to a database. I would also think that going with a Web API would make it a faster app since it's depending on cellular access for it's communication. JSON should be a smaller payload than XML.

So, I would like to just re-write it using Web API 2 and Entity Framework. However, I'm afraid I'm stuck to using WS since I don't have access to the client code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly broad architectural suggestion, but what you're proposing certainly sounds possible and even quite reasonable.

If I understand correctly, you currently have this:

```
Client -> ASMX Service
```

And you can't change the Client, only the ASMX Service.  The first thing you're going to want to do this ensure that server-side business logic is de-coupled from the platform technology:

```
Client -> ASMX Service -> Business Logic
```

The idea here is that any application host should be able to reasonably invoke the same business logic, even if that logic is nothing more than direct database access.  The application host itself should be little more than a pass-through set of operations to be invoked.

At that point, you can create a second application host alongside the first one:

```
Client -> ASMX Service ----|
                           |-> Business Logic
          WebAPI Service --|
```

So now you have two different services which expose the same business logic, using two different web service technologies.  Each of them should be very thin, as application host technologies should always be easily replaceable.

At this point, assuming there are no significant gaps in the operations available between the two services, you can publish the new service's specifications to clients and begin plans to deprecate the old service.  When you can deprecate it is more of a contractual issue than a technical issue.  However long you've committed to maintaining it, that's how long clients will have a reasonable expectation to still use it.

If you *really* want to, you can even have the ASMX Service be a pass-through to the WebAPI Service, but in my personal experience that adds unnecessary layering to the whole setup and artificially complicates the abstraction of the business logic.  Either way, the interface exposed by the ASMX Service wouldn't change.

---

The main thing here is the logical abstraction of the operations being exposed and the analysis of any gaps between what the ASMX Service can do and what the WebAPI Service can do.  If that gets complex, then that's an indication that the business logic (and indeed the whole solution domain) is tightly coupled to the application technology being used, namely ASMX web services.  *That* is the problem to be solved.  Once solved, creating different application hosts and exposing different services which invoke the same underlying business operations becomes almost trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You are right; you are stuck if you can't change the client and you want to change service protocols. Your client currently has a specific .asmx endpoint it is configured to point to and until you can update that endpoint and have the client stop using the proxy generated from the service, you can't change to Web API.

I'd still rewrite the service to use EF, though.